# Vuetify: grid layout with five columns

Tags: vuetify.js

Vuetify uses a 12-point grid system. Since 12 is not divisible by 5, how does one create a grid with 5 columns of the same width? The 5 columns should take all available space.

What's the most "correct" way to do this?

EDIT:
I tried to implement John M's comment, but it doesn't fill up all the available horizontal space:

```
<v-container>
  <v-card color="red">
    <v-layout wrap align-content-space-around text-xs-center>
      <v-flex xs1></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">1</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">2</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">3</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">4</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">5</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs1></v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-card>
</v-container>
```

I want the red areas to be gone:
[image]

Comment: |_|__|__|__|__|__|_| Like that. 1 column blank  5x2 content  and 1 column blank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed a five columns layout too, and I found something that's working for me. I needed the five columns layout for `lg` screens, so I added these rules in my css:

https://codepen.io/rekam/pen/JmNPPx

```
/* vuetify lg min breakpoint: 1280 - 16     = 1264px */
/* vuetify lg max breakpoint: 1920 - 16 - 1 = 1903px */

@media (min-width: 1264px) and (max-width: 1903px) {
    .flex.lg5-custom {
        width: 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
        flex-basis: 20%;
    }
}
```

You need to specify min and max in media query, because of you don't, the `20%` rule will apply for all sizes. And simply use it in your template like this:

```
<!-- md4 is just here as an example -->
<v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 1</v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 2</v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 3</v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 4</v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 5</v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 6</v-flex>
    <v-flex md4 class="lg5-custom">box 7</v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Comment: This works for me too, thanks. I want 5 columns for all screen sizes so I can even leave out the min and max. I still wonder though if there's a solution without having to specify a css rule-set.

Comment: If you just use <v-flex> without anything else, the divs will adjust in equal proportion. If you have always 5 elements, whatever the size of the screen, you can create new row every five items and it should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

What i needed was 5 column grid after medium display size
i wrote a inline style with a breakpoint condition

```
  <v-row>
    <v-col v-for="n in 10"
         :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? ' flex: 1 0 18%;' : ''"
         cols="6"
         sm="3" >
         {{items inside each column}}
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the content have to be in a card component? I'm asking because it wasn't specified in your question. If it isn't, you can accomplish this by removing the card component and replacing/adding some props to your container and layout components.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-container align-center text-xs-center>
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">1</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">2</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">3</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">4</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs2><v-card color="blue"><v-card-text class="px-0">5</v-card-text></v-card></v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a card component, but the card was there to show the red area's. This is how it looks like if I put them beneath each other: [image](https://i.imgur.com/uiQ37XC.png). So I think your solution has the same issue: it doesn't fill up all available horizontal space.

Comment: This approach does not work for more then 5 elements

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the cols number `<v-col cols="12">` write `xl="auto"`

```
<v-col xl="auto">
```